# How to have programs launch on startup that requires UAC in win 8.1?

Tags: windows-8.1, uac

I know you can drag and drop a shortcut of a program you want to start after you log in automatically. "C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\" But what if a program requires user account control? is there a way to remove account control for a program if I trust it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A work-around that some programs (e.g. Restore point Creator) use is to create a task in Windows *Task Scheduler* with *Action* to "Start a program", and allow it to run on demand. This has the merits of providing a place to comment the use of the task, and the ability to disable or remove it at will. There are tutorials at http://www.7tutorials.com/use-task-scheduler-launch-programs-without-uac-prompts and http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/windows-and-office/run-uac-restricted-programs-without-the-uac-prompt/.

Some other alternatives at https://www.raymond.cc/blog/task-scheduler-bypass-uac-prompt/ require third-party tools.

There **is** a way to actually set UAC policies, suggested by Microsoft at http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-security/uac-and-one-program-used-very-regulary/67bfc4b5-faff-4de4-be48-f395bf1c519d, but it requires the *Local Security Policy* Control Panel applet, found in Windows 8 Ultimate, Professional and Enterprise editions, and **not in Home Premium or Basic editions**.